# .htaccess issue with using a -org secondary domain vs using a .com secondary domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have successfully forwarded www.atlantalawvideo.legalvideoconsulting.com to www.atlantalawvideo.com for SEO purposes.

I'm using this code in my .htaccess file in my /atlantalawvideo/ folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.atlantalawvideo.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.atlantalawvideo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm having trouble forwarding www.legalvideographer-org.legalvideoconsulting.com to www.legalvideographer.org

I'm using this code in my .htaccess file in my /legalvideographer-org/ folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.legalvideographer.org
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.legalvideographer.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Not sure what the problem is http://www.legalvideographer-org.legalvideoconsulting.com forward goes nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second rewrite is not working because you are not meeting the condition of the `%{HTTP_HOST}`. You're not using the full host name to check. `legalvideographer.org` appears to be a `subdomain` of`legalvideoconsulting.com`. See if this works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.legalvideographer-org\.legalvideoconsulting\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.legalvideographer.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That should work if that is your domain name.

You should also be able to do a simple redirect instead of the rewrite rule

```
redirct 301 / http://www.legalvideographer.org
```

Comment: I tried putting in your code verbatim and with legalvi3 as my server name; I think that's the right server name. In both instances I get a "page isn't redirecting properly" error.

Comment: What do you mean with legalvi3 as server name? if the %{SERVER_NAME} in apache is set correctly it the code shouldn't need to be changed.

Comment: Well then the code isn't working. And you are correct... legalvideographer.org is a subdomain of legalvideoconsulting.com

Comment: is it legalvideographer-org or legalvideographer.org?

Comment: You're right. I meant legalvideographer-org insofar as the context www.legalvideographer-org.legalvideoconsulting.com

Comment: I'm getting the error "too many redirects trying to open legalvideographer.org" with Safari

Comment: Chrome says redirect loop

Comment: Is this htaccess on the same server as other sites? or does this subdomain have it's own htaccess?

Comment: The subdomain has its own htaccess file and all the sites are on the same server as far as I know

Comment: My fault I had made a mistake on the condition. Try that.

Comment: Success! Thanks for helping me out.